# Getting Client computer name ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net

We are using :

System.Net.Dns.Resolve(Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")).HostName

to get the client computer name in ASP .NET.

It works fine when run from visual studio, and even when run from IIS7, but IIS6 (or maybe some other factor) is only returning the client computer's domain name

Are there any settings or anything that would cause this function to return the domain name instead of the intended machine name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dns.Resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve.aspx) is now obsolete and so thatmight be causing the issue. Try using [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143996%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the cause of the issue is but this may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.hostname.aspx

> The HostName property contains the primary host name for a server. If the DNS entry for the server defines additional aliases, they will be available in the Aliases property.

It is possible that there are additional DNS entries and `Aliases` may contain what you are looking for.